# Regex end of capture string

Tags: regex

Can anyone tell me why this regex:

```
(<\s*script\s*>.*<\s*\/*script\s*>)
```

Matches this entire line:

```
<  script  >  some more javascript</script>     ggg     <script>
```

Comment: no link available for me

Comment: it deleted the link, won't let me add it in for another 90 mins :-( will post it in later

Comment: Because you are using greedy dot matching. Use `[\s\S]*?` or more proper DOM parser.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xMoQC.jpg

Comment: ^ (link above works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. First a simple mistake, you are making the termination switch match 0 or more `'/'` characters by using the `*` quantifier. You can solve that by removing the quantifier. *Requiring* a single termination switch, changing your regex to: `(<\s*script\s*>.*<\s*\/script\s*>)`
2. But second, because `.*` is greedy. This means it grabs as much as it can while still matching the rest of the regex. In this case: `<\s*\/*script\s*>`. This means that if you had multiple "...<\script>"s on a line it would match the entire line rather than each "...".

What you want is to match any character as *few* times as possible. Which is called lazy matching. You can qualify any quantifier with `?` to accomplish this, in your example:

```
.*?
```

Using that your regex would become:

```
(<\s*script\s*>.*?<\s*\/script\s*>)
```

If you're actually using the http://www.regexr.com "Reference" menu to build your regex, you can find this under "Quantifiers and Alternation">"Lazy"

Answer (score 1):

Replace **\/*** by **\/**.

**\/*** match **0** or more "/".